# Generalised pigeonhole principle question

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

**Question:** Proof
Every set $S$ of $20$ integers between $0$ and $188$ contains four distinct elements $x,y,z,w$ such that $189$ divides $(x-y+z-w)$

**Hints:** Consider their pairwise sums modulo $189$.

**My insights:**
I work out some scratches:
$189$'s factors: $\{1,3,7,9,21,27,63\}$

take factor $3$ , it can be sum of $\{1,2\}$,$\{3,0\}$,$\{4,-1\}$, $\{5,-2\}$, $\{6,-3\},\dots , \{188,-185\}$

There is too much information, I can't see their connections *(who are the pigeon and who are the holes)* and where to apply the hint.

Comment: How many pairs of two elements $(x,z)$ are there in $S$?

Comment: update: let x-y be a , z-w be b.

Therefore take factor 3 , it can be sum of {a,b} :{1,2},{3,0},etc

sorry for misleading

Comment: there is 187 pairs of {a,b} for factor 3
for factor 7,there are 185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the pair-wise sums of the $20$ selected elements. If any two of these are equal, say $k+l = m+n$, then we can put these directly into the formula as $(k-m+l-n)$ for a result of zero, which is divisible by $189$.

Otherwise we will have $190$ distinct results. However, considering these sums $\bmod 189$, two of these values must be equivalent by the pigeonhole principle and so we can again use these two in the formula to get a number divisible by $189$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** How many pairs of two distinct elements are ?

**Hint 2** If two pairs have the same sum modulo $189$, can some of the elements be equal?

Comment: sorry, can't see the use of hints.The number of distinct elements of is different is different for each factor.For hints 2 ,if two pairs have the same modulo 189 ,like {1,2} and {3,0}. The x,y,z,w can be different

Comment: @HaHaman You have 20 elements, how does this number changes with the factors? And you should not worry about the factors, work directly modulo 189....

Comment: well,my interpretation is like this:

for 189 divides (x-y+z-w),it must equal to {1,3,7,9,21,27,63} anyone of them

and then for 3 , it can be combination of  2,3,2,0 thus
3-4+2-0

Comment: i work from the factors first.Thank you for helping by the way

Comment: so i don't know what to answer for" How many pairs of two distinct elements are ?"
so i claim that for each factors ,it's different

Comment: @HaHaman If you pick 2 elements out of 20, the answer is the same no matter what unrelated thing you want to do.

Comment: thanks,now i know i have focused on the wrong side.